# Haskell utility to make function point free

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, pointfree, combinatory-logic

I'd like to quickly and correctly reduce functions to point free form in Haskell. I'd prefer to produce fairly readable outcomes. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 11):

There is actually a program called "pointfree"

Do this

```
cabal install pointfree
```

then this at the command line

```
> pointfree "\x -> x+1"

 (1 +)
```

Warning- although some pointfree outcomes are wonderful, others are pretty scary....

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell wiki covers tools for [pointfree refactoring here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree#Tool_support). It mainly covers [Lambdabot](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot), an IRC bot that does pointfree and pointful refactoring:

```
@pl \x y -> EQ == compare x y
((EQ ==) .) . compare
```

[1] Example from http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=19908612&timestamp=1421726397#t1421726397